# Как вывести из базы все данные, которые входят в промежуток между дат?

Tags: php, mysql

Eсть база `news` с полями:

```
| id | title     | batetime
--------------------------------------
|  1 | блаблабла | 2014-03-14 10:35:20
```

Нужно вывести, например, все новости, которые находятся в промежутке между датами `2014-03-10` и `2014-03-20`

**Как правильно сделать запрос MySql?**

Пробовал, получается полная ересь...

Comment: Что вы пробовали? Приведите пример неработающего запроса.

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE datetime>='.$date_go.' and datetime<='.$date_to.'");

Comment: И какое было сообщение об ошибке? В каком формате были значения $date_go и $date_to? Как минимум в приведённом запросе пропущены кавычки у строк в запросе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE batetime BETWEEN '2014-03-10' AND '2014-03-20'
```

Comment: сердечно благодарю!